# Use Python to edit XML header

Tags: python, xml

I've written a Python script to create some XML, but I didn't find a way to edit the heading within Python.

Basically, instead of having this as my heading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

I need to have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

I looked into this as best I could, but found no way to add standalone status from within Python. So I figured that I'd have to go over the file after it had been created and then replace the text. I read in several places that I should stay far away from using readlines() because it could ruin the XML formatting.

Currently the code I have to do this - which I got from another Stackoverflow post about editing XML with Python - is:

```
doc = parse('file.xml')
elem = doc.find('xml version="1.0"')
elem.text = 'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"'
```

That provides me with a KeyError. I've tried to debug it to no avail, which leads me to believe that perhaps the XML heading wasn't meant to be edited in this way. Or my code is just wrong.

If anyone is curious (or miraculously knows how to insert standalone status into Python code), here is my code to write the xml file:

```
with open('file.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(doc.toprettyxml(indent='                '))
```

Some people don't like "toprettyxml", but with my relatively basic level, it seemed like the best bet.

Anyway, if anyone can provide some advice or insight, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What API are you using, and what python version?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python 2.7.3 and I'm using IDLE. Thanks.

Comment: IDLE is an IDE, not an XML API. Are you using the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, my bad. Yes, I am using xml.etree.ElementTree. Although I also have xml.dom.minidom within my script. Like I said, I'm not too advanced with all this (especially creating xml within Python), so I tried to work with things I found around the Internet and modify them for my needs.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the preamble? utf8 is the default encoding..no idea about standalone....what is the usecase?

Comment: @user1833746 I have a script that will download and go through some error logs, and then create an XML file that can be run by Apache ANT to be added to Quality Center. The people I consulted with were pretty sure that the ANT script required the encoding and the standalone status to be stated. Also, from what I read the default standalone status is "yes".

Comment: @CreativeName: No, the default status is `no` where it matters; e.g. there are references in the document. The XML standard defines `UTF-8` as the default encoding, and most XML formatters omit the encoding from the declaration.

Comment: ["If there are external markup declarations but there is no standalone document declaration, the value "no" is assumed."](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-rmd)

Comment: Do all of your files have an xml header? If so, why not simply replace the first line in every file, rather than trying to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xml.etree` API does not give you any options to write out a `standalone` attribute in the XML declaration.

You may want to use the [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/api/index.html) instead; it uses the same ElementTree API, but offers more control over the output. [`tostring()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) supports a `standalone` flag:

```
from lxml import etree

etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, standalone=False)
```

or use [`.write()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write), which support the same options:

```
doc.write(outputfile, pretty_print=True, standalone=False)
```

Comment: I came across that, but was hoping to stick to the Python Standard Library. I suppose that may not be doable at this point. I'll try lxml out.

Comment: @CreativeName: the alternative is to write out the declaration yourself before writing the rest of the XML without a declaration.